# Can not perform POST request with JQuery to Parse.com Express.JS application

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Hello I try to send a POST request the following way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/posttest',
        type: 'post',
        // dataType: json,
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Succes");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error");
    }
    });
```

In Express JS the code looks like this:

```
app.post("/posttest",function(req,res){
res.json({ message: "OK" });     
});
```

But the browser gives me constantly the following error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (posttest, line 0)
```

I have no idea why :(

EDIT: This says the Parse.com console log

```
Bad Request: Bad Request
at next (connect_proto.js:133:13)
at connect_bodyParser.js:57:23
at null.<anonymous> (connect_json.js:71:18)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
at handleRequest (http.js:557:11)
at Parse.Cloud._runCustomEndpoint (<anonymous>:146:7)
```

Comment: On the client side via jQuery

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood. I'm not very familiar with Express.

Comment: Why do you have `dataType: json` commented out? I missed that earlier. That could be significant.

Comment: On further consideration, I'm deleting my answer for now. Your client-side code looked fine to me, but now I'm not sure it's right for a JSON request (I don't usually write those by hand). `data: {}` may not be correct.

Comment: I did set the dataType now, did not change anything. I tried to do the POST request with the REST console for chrome. It worked, the Response was the string "OK", just as it should be.